# Featured Image in RSS Feed

Tags: plugins, rss, feed

I'm using the following code to add a featured image to my rss feed in wordpress.

```
add_action( 'rss2_item', 'add_post_featured_image_as_rss_item_enclosure' );

function add_post_featured_image_as_rss_item_enclosure() {
if ( ! has_post_thumbnail() )
    return;

$thumbnail_size = apply_filters( 'rss_enclosure_image_size', 'thumbnail' );
$thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() );
$thumbnail = image_get_intermediate_size( $thumbnail_id, $thumbnail_size );

if ( empty( $thumbnail ) )
    return;

$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

 printf( 
    '<enclosure url="%s" length="%s" type="%s" />',
    $thumbnail['url'], 
    filesize( path_join( $upload_dir['basedir'], $thumbnail['path'] ) ), 
    get_post_mime_type( $thumbnail_id ) 
 );
}
```

But the plguin above is outputting a really small image 150x150. I tried changing the thumbnail size to full or large, but it won't work. Is there any way to add a url to the full featured image size in the enclosure field below?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `get_post_thumbnail_id` to get the ID of the thumbnail, then with the function [`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) you can get the image of the size you want, including full size, using the second paramenter.

```
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID());    
$thumb_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumb_id, 'full');
```

Now in `$thumb_data` you have a nice array, or `false` if there's no image.

The array has this structure:

> [0] => url
>
> [1] => width
>
> [2] => height
>
> [3] => boolean: true if $url is a resized image, false if it is the
>   original.

Answer (score 0):

On the line below, you just need to change "thumbnail" at the end to "large".  That should do the trick

`$thumbnail_size = apply_filters( 'rss_enclosure_image_size', 'thumbnail' );`